# Is there a way to communicate information between puppet classes/resources

Tags: puppet, icinga2

Is there a way to communicate information between classes/resources?

I have a profile that I want to include on all nodes to set them up as being monitored by Icinga which uses an exported resource :

```
class profile::icinga2::host {
  @@::icinga2::object::host { $::fqdn:
      display_name     => $::fqdn,
      address          => $::ipaddress,
      vars             => hiera_hash('icinga_vars',{}) + {
         "dns_lookup" => $::fqdn,
         "dns_expected_answers" => $::ipaddress,
      },
      target           => "/etc/icinga2/conf.d/puppet.d/${::fqdn}.conf"
  }
}
```

These resources are then declared in the icinga server using the resource collector:

```
<<| icinga2::object::host|>>
```

I want to be able to customize the vars entry in the profile::icinga2::host resource and at the moment doing by adding icinga_vars data into the hiera yaml file for the node e.g.:

```
icinga_vars:
    http_uri: "http://puppetboard.zoo.lan"
```

However ideally I would do this inside any classes that are included by the node itself.

Is there a way of setting up data in classes that can then be read by a different class?

Facts don’t seem the right way of doing it and nor does puppetdb, is there an alternative?

Can I, for example, create a icinga2::variable class and declare those outside the profile::icinga2::host class and then iterate over them in the profile::icinga2::host class?  How would that be done and how would dependencies be handled e.g. I would need to ensure the icinga2::variables are ready to be read by profile::icinga2::host
Thanks

Comment: I must be missing something here, why wouldn't you do this in hiera? Then the variables will be available to all classes with a lookup.

Comment: the data to be added is resource specific not host specific hence why I want to put it into a resource.

Comment: If it is added to common.yaml it will be available for all resources